# Consequences of Changing Github Repository

Tags: github, repository, rename

- I want to change the name of my Github Repository.
- What are the consequences of doing so?
- Is there a negative impact anywhere on my project?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name of your repository changes the URLs to it.  GitHub will try to rewrite the URLs for the old name in most cases, but it's possible that any links that people had to your repository elsewhere on the Internet may be broken.  For example, you or others may have automated systems which are designed to access the repository, and those may stop working.

Things will definitely break if you create a new repository with the same name as the old one, because in that case GitHub obviously cannot rewrite any URLs.  That should be avoided unless you're certain you know what you're doing.

Comment: I just started a project. No one is aware of the project or has any link to that repository. I just wanted to change the name of the repo as I had a better name. So that won't be a problem, right?

Comment: Nope, shouldn't be.